# Unable to get ROS Husky Simulation Tutorial to Work

Tags: husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just started using ROS, and have been using the Clearpath Robotics tutorials to get my head around it.

They have a tutorial 'Drive a Husky' https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/categories/200165835-ROS

I have installed the components and I can load up the Gazebo simulator and RViz, however when I get to the line

```
rostopic pub /husky/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 100 '[0.5,0,0]' '[0,0,0]'
```

nothing happens. According to the tutorial this is supposed to make the robot in the simulation move forwards.

This may be something trivial that I have overlooked but I am very new to ROS and have no idea how to troubleshoot the problem. All the answers I have come accross so far just say that entering the command into a new terminal window will work - but it doesn't.

I am using ROS Indigo on Mint 17.1 Rebecca.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207058/unable-to-get-ros-husky-simulation-tutorial-to-work/) by [fborok](https://answers.ros.org/users/22139/fborok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

> $ rostopic pub /husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 100 '[0.5,0,0]' '[0,0,0]'

as rohit.ros stated, this is the topic that has velocity controller.

---

Originally posted by [zimmermegan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23536/zimmermegan/) with karma: 26 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1